# Unable to install composer on Windows Server 2012 - Open_basedir restriction in effect

Tags: php, windows, composer-php

I would like to install composer on a windows server 2012 - but after installing PHP7 i am unable to install/configurate it anymore.

It was already installed with PHP 5.6.16 - but i was unable to install any package with composer. I always gets the error:

**Open_basedir restriction in effect**

After trying about 2 hours, ill ill tried to reinstall composer again, to set the new paths for PHP7.

But now when ill try to install composer again, ill get the following error:

Connection Error [ERR_CONNECTION]: Unable to connect to getcomposer.org

```
Request to https://getcomposer.org/installer failed with errors:
Open_basedir restriction in effect. File(https://getcomposer.org/installer) is not within the allowed path(s): (C:\inetpub\wwwroot;C:\php-5.6.16-nts-Win32-VC9-x86\temp;c:\usr\local\ssl\certs;.;C:\composer)
```

There is no open_basedir config in my php.ini. It is also impossible to setup the PHP.exe from PHP7 to work with composer (need to setup the 5.6 Version when ill use the composer installer)

Any ideas? Is there another config file? What does this restriction mean?

Comment: Most likely it's actually a firewall issue on Windows.

Comment: Also, could be ssl certificates... have a look at this: https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/2798#issuecomment-133869395

Btw... if these 2 things do solve it I'll add it as an answer for you to accept :)

Comment: Thanks for your answers. But when i tried to install a new laravel Project with the old working Composer - the Download of laravel was Fine - (so Download was 100%) - but then when eh tried to install ill received the same error.